# Getting net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET 200 (OK) on js / css files served by service worker

Tags: caching, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

**UPD 22.02.2019** https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=934386

I am extensively testing my caching service worker and I do get sometimes the `net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET 200 (OK)` error for js / css files that are served by service worker.
I am using **workbox 3.6.3**

Steps to reproduce:

- stop service worker
- drop all caches
- first page reload - my webpage is loaded and service worker is installed
- second page reload - sometimes I am getting an **error** here that looks like this `GET https://dev-host.com/client/build/_/12.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET 200 (OK)`

What happens in browser:

- my script is loaded via `script` tag that is created and inserted into the `head` tag of the webpage. All this is done by `requireEnsure` function from a manifest.js script generated by webpack - https://gist.github.com/chestozo/acd651382f9590988d4679f8dbb21d19.
- as I can see script request is intercepted by service worker that performs script fetch and stores it in cache
- then I can see that initial request takes some time and then fails

[image: Network panel]

- first request initiated by `script` tag being inserted into the `head`
- second request - done by service worker; it succeeds

Here you can see that file request is being intercepted by workbox:

[image: File request goes via service worker]

And finally that initial request fails:
[image: Request failure]

This is what my service worker script looks like `sw.js`:

```
workbox.skipWaiting();
workbox.clientsClaim();

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    new RegExp(reRuntimeStatic),
    workbox.strategies.cacheFirst({
        cacheName: CACHE_NAMES.STATIC,
        plugins: [
            new workbox.cacheableResponse.Plugin({
                statuses: [ 200 ]
            }),
            new workbox.expiration.Plugin({
                maxAgeSeconds: 5 * 60 * 60 * 24,
                maxEntries: 100
            })
        ]
    }),
    'GET'
);

self.__precacheManifest = [].concat(cacheConfig.precache || []);
workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(self.__precacheManifest, {});
```

Any idea what is happening here?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if this is related, but does it change anything if you move your call to `workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(self.__precacheManifest, {});` so that it comes before your call to `workbox.routing.registerRoute()`? In your current configuration, your cacheFirst route takes precedence over the route that's created for your precached assets, and that's probably not what you want.

Comment: Thanks for you reply.  
I will change it but I have to say that I was moving things around and originally it was like you suggest.. But I will try it anyway.

Comment: It didn't help :/ Also I have checked that I am having this issue with `Network / Disable cache` checkbox set in DevTools or without.

Comment: I could verify that we are calling `event.respondWith(responsePromise);` inside `fetch` event handler and that `responsePromise` is resolved with `Response` object. Still we are getting `onerror` handler called on `<script/>` before script is executed. Maybe somehow we are dealing with garbage collection inside service worker?

Comment: Here is my guess:
sw is intercepting big file request, it makes his own `fetch` call to store Response inside the cache. All goes fine.  
Finally `event.respondWith(responsePromise)` is called and at this point sw has done his job. And basically sw does not know what should happen after that and for how long it should keep the Response object. And at some point Response object is destroyed. And when `<script/>` is ready to execute - Response is not available anymore. And this is kind of network problem for `<script/>` that's why we get `net::` error. Is it possible?